# How to do this nodal analysis problem with voltages sources plus a series resistance

Tags: dc, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but it seems I got every number close to the answer but not the answer itself.

Here is the circuit:
[image]

For my first try I took the top node as V1 and the bottom as the reference node. I then did KCL at V1 to yield \$V_1 \div 50 = I_b - 60Ib \div 150\$ which simplified to \$V1 = 70I_b\$.

I then did a KVL around the left loop (still wrong answer if I try with Ohm's law or any other way) to get \$-24 + 250I_b + V_1 = 0\$. This is the same as \$V_1 = 24 - 250I_b\$.

Solving these equations gives me 75 mA for \$I_b\$. But the given answer is 79.34 mA. I am even more confused because when I put the circuit into LTSpice I get -88 mA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Redraw the circuit like this and show the currents: -

[image]

You now have \$61\cdot I_b\$ flowing through the 50 Ω resistor. This should help you solve it.

Comment: Doing this I was able to get the correct answer, but I have no idea why this worked when nothing else I tried did.

Comment: @xormapmap my advice is always redraw a circuit to make it clearer and mark on the currents. That's all I did because I could see you got into a mess with your first formula.

Answer (score 1):

> For my first try I took the top node as V1 and the bottom as the reference node.

Okay. So, turns into this:

[image]

> I then did KCL at V1 to yield \$V1÷50=Ib−60Ib÷150\$ which simplified to \$V1=70Ib\$.

There you go. Your first mistake. According to your assumption, the current flowing through the dependent source (let's call it \$I_y\$) has a direction from V1 towards dependent source: \$I_b=I_x+I_y\$. The problem is \$I_y\neq 60\ I_b \ / \ 150\$.

Make the following change and redo the calculations:
\$V_1 = 60 \ I_b + 150 \ I_y\$

Answer (score 0):

As Andy suggested, it really helps to redraw the schematic. It's not necessary. But it often helps you to avoid making mistakes. So let's start with that step.

You already mentioned selecting the bottom node as ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZMZWb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I swapped around the dependent voltage source and its resistor. Which is fine, as they were in series with each other.

That's it. The KCL is trivial as you know that \$I_{_\text{B}}=\frac{+24\:\text{V}-V_{_\text{X}}}{R_1}\$:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{_\text{X}}}{R_3}=\frac{+24\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{60\left[\frac{+24\:\text{V}-V_{_\text{X}}}{R_1}\right]}{R_3}$$

You should be able to solve that for \$V_{_\text{X}}\$. And from there everything else you may want just falls out, even more trivially.